# Youtube-dl module, getting part file instead of mp4 file when interrupting

Tags: python-3.x, interrupt, youtube-dl

When I interrupt the download process (by pressing ctrl + c), instead of getting an mp4 file, I get a part file. I also get the following messages :

```
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
ERROR: ffmpeg exited with code 255
```

This is the part of the code :

```
self.ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([self.download_url])
```

**Also I forgot to mention that if change the filename from `filename.mp4.part` to **`finemame.mp4`** I can watch the video normally.**

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behaviour is wanted since you should be able to restart the download. It will or at least should then continue downloading from where you stopped.

You could try to use
`--no-part` when using on command line
or set `nopart` to `True` when using embedded youtube-dl
This will write the output directly.

Comment: And what if i want to save the mp4 file before the stream ends? Also I don't think that this behaviour is normal, because when I do the same thing via cmd, I get the mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, i had to use `os.rename(old_title,new_title)` where, `old_title = video_title+'.part'` and `new_title = video_title+'.mp4'` But still, this is not normal, when I do the same thing via cmd the program returns an mp4, anyway, that works for me!